# How to access localhost via https with a valid certificate

Tags: ssl, https, certificate

We have a Web-Application that should interact with a desktop application that has a helper tool character (e.g. no setup, no need for admin privileges). The helper is listening via http/https on a simple port bound to localhost.

The Web-Application uses a SSL certificate. Every customer has a machine on its own for his data. For claryfication: The Web-Application is running on a server, serving one customer but multiple people.

The problem is, the Web-Application cannot reach the helper tool via https (using image or iframe). The main issue is, that the local webserver listening on localhost has no signed certificate. So the web browser is blocking the interaction.

Is there any way to get around this trouble? I think, I cannot get a certificate for localhost, because no one would sign it.

I know, that I cannot use XMLHttpRequest for this, but that's not the point.

The goal is to have a customer friendly - no install - just works - solution. The customer should not do ANY configuration. Just downloading and starting the tool. We'd like to have a direct communication to the tool (e.g. no outbound direction to the web server).

Is the any solution for this?

Comment: If the application runs for each customer on there own, local machine, then I wonder why you bother with https on the localhost at all. To sniff out the communication packages on localhost, an attacker must have direct access to the machine. When that happens, there are easier ways to attack your application. Therefor https won't increase the security of your application.

Comment: Sorry, I added a clarification. The Web-Application runs on a server (per customer). The helper tool is running on the client machines. It should add some extra features that cannot be accessed by the Web-Application, because the server has no access to the clients computer.

Comment: Have you tried to use a http connection to localhost at all. I ask this to check whether your problem is indeed a problem with the ssl connection or if the application starts the request to localhost on the server and not on the client.

Comment: I'm correctly talking to the client (from within the web-application). When disabling https (and switching to http - web-application AND client), all works fine. Installing a self signed CRT for localhost on the client side also works. But that's not solving the "no install - just work" solution, because the client need administrator rights to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If it is Active-directory environment , you can create your own CA and sign  certificates and distribute them across the domain.   also you can add to trusted sites through domain policies  this way client side you don't need to configure anything .

Comment: Every customer has different server/client environments. The server is accessible via intranet AND the internet. So any PC can open the Web-Application and start the tool.

Comment: So , in every intranet there will be one server running the web application and all clients will access that server right ?.  typically  SSL certificates bind to  domain . If  you are able to resolve host names on intranet , you can push SSL certificates  by using  automated login scripts .

Comment: Hmm, no, that's would not work. See the Web-Application as an Website, that CAN be used via Intranet, but also via Internet. I have NO control over the clients environment. It's possible to login from the outside. So I cannot install a certificate via logon scripts. The question is: Is there any why to skip this step?

Comment: Then you must configure a public ip to their web server and get a certificate signed by a trusted CA . So you no certificate error while accessing it from either intranet or internet with public domain name . I don't see any other option .

Comment: The helper tool is listening on localhost. How should I get a signed certificate for "localhost"? The Web-Application must talk to the helper tool, note vice versa.

Comment: @SuperNova, did you got with a solution? I have the same question. thanks in advance.

Comment: @JordyBaylac Sorry, I never got a working solution for this. We solved it otherway: The server side solution does not make any XMLHttpRequests to the localhost. We're just navigation to the target now.